# Showing colour in cal-heatmap tiles

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, cal-heatmap

I'm using cal-heatmap for displaying a user activity for a month. My issue is that the colour change is not showing properly. My "init" function is given below.

When I provide data with integer values which have difference of 2 or 3 (eg: 8, 12, 3, 7 etc [pls note that I'm giving data as JSON]), I can't see any significant difference in colour for the blocks (screenshot is added in https://i.stack.imgur.com/xspWR.jpg - numbers given in top indicates the data corresponding to that cell). 
[image: numbers given in top indicates the data corresponding to that cell]

```
init({
    start: new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), month, 1),
    cellRadius: 35,
    cellSize: 58,
    itemSelector: "#heatmap_busiestDays",
    domain: "month", //hour|day|week|month|year
    subDomain: "x_day",
    subDomainTextFormat: "%b %d",
    range: 1,
    domainGutter: 10,
    previousSelector: "#cal-heatmap-previous",
    nextSelector: "#cal-heatmap-next",

    displayLegend: false,
    data: busiestDayHeatMap,

    legendColors: {
        min: "#A2F37B",
        max: "#26911F",
        empty: "white"
    }
});
```

Am I missing anything in settings? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you parsing data on _afterLoadData(data)_ ?